# Is the "Prerendered Icon Flag" bug fixed?

Tags: app-store-connect

I've been reading the previous posts on this and it looked like the bug was fixed, but after an update, I'm having the same bug now. Apologies if any of the below is repetitive.

I recently updated my app. The .plist has Prerendered Icon Flag: true, and Icon already includes gloss effect: YES. However, in iTunes Connect the 512x512 icon has the big gloss over it? I went to check the binary details in iTunes Connect too and the Prerendered Icon Flag says false even though in the plist it's set to true?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can anyone help? My app just went LIVE today and it looks like the big gloss is still over it. :(

Comment: I had this happen to me when I first uploaded my binary and the status said Binary Uploaded (or something like). But a couple minutes later, the status changed to Waiting For Review and the gloss went away and Prerendered Icon Flag changed from false to true.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you are adhering to the new iOS 5 icon layout in your `.plist`. If your strings such as "Icon already includes gloss effect" are now within the "Icon files (iOS 5)" dictionary, they will not be applied on iOS 5 devices.

[image]